# Apache Commons VFS2 doesn't release a lock after processing a zip file

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-vfs

Can you help me to find a way how to force the library to properly close files and allow other processes to further modified them.Currently when files are processed by the below code snippet they are kept by the application and cannot be modified.

```
            //input represents FileObject zip file         
            FileObject zip = fsManager.createFileSystem(input); //auxiliary variable used for extracting zip file content (input)
            tmpDir.copyFrom(zip, new AllFileSelector());
            zip.close(); // it's closed properly
           // input.close() or ((AbstractFileSystem)input.getFileSystem()).close() doesn't help to release the lock
```

Comment: I am having the EXACT same issue.  Wish someone could help answer this.  I've been thoroughly underwhelmed with Apache Commons VFS.  The documentation is poor and the API is tough to use.